# How to create a method to Print an array in JOption Pane

Tags: java, arrays

I've been having trouble in trying to create a method that will print an array in `JOPtionPane` on one dialogue box instead of many, I am also having difficulty printing the actual content of the array and instead I am only able to print the address of the array. My code so far is below and I'm not exactly sure how to advance it so I can Print my arrays using `JOptionPane`. All suggestions and corrections are appreciated.

```
public static void printArray(int [] array)
{
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, array[i]);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just join the elements of your array as a String first:

```
private static String joinArray(int[] array)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(array[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void printArray(int[] array)
{
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, joinArray(array));
}
```